# Laravel - Push queue task with a custom handling method and deleting job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, iron.io, push-queue

Consider this kind of code which pushes a task to queue to run a custom handler method that is located within the same class:

```
<?php namespace Space;

class Spaceship {

    public static function cruise()
    {
        // Throtting in 3 seconds...
        Queue::later(3, '\Space\Spaceship@throttle', $coordinates, 'queue-name');
    }

    public static function throttle($job, $data)
    {
        $job->delete();
        return 'ok';
    }

}
```

This worked fine before I added $job->delete(); but now its giving an error:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function delete() on a non-object
```

In [Laravel 4.2 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#push-queues) there is no explanation why with a push queue task pointed to a custom handler method you wouldn't need to explicitly delete the task from the queue with $job->delete() ? Yet that kind of implementation works and when the $job parameter is logged, it's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `app\config\queue.php` and check the `default` key. If the latter is set to `sync`, then the above behaviour is expected.

`sync` driver runs your task immediately, which means, `Queue::later` is in truth `Queue::push`.

Try converting your `Queue::later` into `Queue::push` and the code will run without errors.

As for explicit deletion of task in the queue, it is for most part, unnecessary. However, you have to account for queue services which don't provide for automatic deletion of the job.

For my part, AWS SQS (Message Queue Service) automatically deletes the job after it is pulled from the queue tube.

Comment: The default is set to "iron"... But it IronMQ deletes the job like AWS SQS it would then explain this behaviour.

Comment: Then yes; if ironMQ automatically deletes the job, its reference is no longer valid(hence the bool false value of `$job`). It has to be said that using AWS SQS and `$job->delete()` didn't throw any errors for me.